# Primefaces p:growl css. How to extend div message background color width

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 5.3 and primefaces cupertino theme 1.0.10.

I'm trying both move the position of the p:growl message and change the width. I'm running into an issue where the background colour yellow does
not fully extend with the text. I've been trying a series of css adjustments but unable to fix it.

[image: growl message]

The following css moves the position of the p:gowl however the width of the yellow background is not affected. How do I increase the width of the yellow background?

```
.ui-growl {   
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 17%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 110px;
    z-index:9999; 
}
```

The primefaces css is as follows

```
* html .ui-growl {
    position: absolute;
}
* html .ui-growl-item {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
* html .ui-growl-icon-close {
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
}
.ui-growl {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 301px;
}
.ui-growl-item-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    opacity: 0.85;
    filter: alpha(opacity=85);
}
.ui-growl-item {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.ui-growl-item p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.ui-growl-icon-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-growl-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 7px 0;
    display: block;
}
.ui-growl-image {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background: url("/stonemanInterface2/faces/javax.faces.resource/messages/messages.png?ln=primefaces&v=5.3") no-repeat;
}
.ui-growl-image-info {
    background-position: 0 -264px;
}
.ui-growl-image-warn {
    background-position: 0 -396px;
}
.ui-growl-image-error {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.ui-growl-image-fatal {
    background-position: 0 -132px;
}
.ui-growl-message {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    width: 220px;
    float: right;
}
.ui-growl-message p {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: What **did** you try? What did the generated html look like. What css was applied? Take a look at all that and try to improve the css that you applied.

Comment: Firebug css tab or similar is your friend, if you don't already use it. You can see the effect immediatly as you try stuff out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, yeah upon inspection it was clear the css was not applied.

The following CSS solved the position and width issues

```
.ui-growl {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 800px;
}


.ui-growl-message {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    width: 95%;
    float: left;
}
```

Mainly though the issue was a resource ordering problem which was solved by putting the stylesheet within the facet named last within the body

```
<h:body>
            <f:facet name="last">
                <h:outputStylesheet library="theme1" name="css/styles/demo.css" />
            </f:facet>
```

As described in [Resource Ordering](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.ui-growl {   
    position:fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 360px;
    height: 110px;
    z-index:9999; 
}
```